# Intellij Problems When Upgrading

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

Hey guys i have been writing a simple DealOrNoDeal game in java using intellij community edition. However on understanding that the community edition lacks the support for Databases in relation to the ultimate edition of intellij. So i installed the ultimate edition, have imported my project and started implementing my db. However now i am i getting a lot of errors in my code that i didn't have in the community edition. Most of which are relating to my Integer objects and also my Scanner object.

Take this line for example:

```
private static Integer[] prizes = {0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 200000, 500000};
```

Intellij is saying i cant initialize my Integer objects with primitive ints. However i believe you are. I am and was using the same jdk for both ides. (1.8)

```
private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)
```

this line also gives me errors about "Usage of API documented since 1.4"

can someone help me please understand these new issues i am facing in intellij ultimate edition.

Also all of my generics are spitting an error saying "Generics are not supported at this language level."

github link: https://github.com/brnabus/DealOrNoDealGame

Comment: Why are you not using an `int[]`? And it sounds like you need to change the compiler version of your project

Comment: Change your language level

Comment: Most likely you have intellij using an old version of Java, as all the issues you describe would result from that.

Comment: Found it language level. Thanks for the fast replies. File>Project Structure> Project Settings> Project > Project Language Level was on Default Java 1.3 changed to 7 - Diamonds, ARM, MultiCatch etc.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

File>Project Structure> Project Settings> Project > Project Language Level was on Default Java 1.3 changed to 5

[image]